# VS2019 Git push. Work Item section missing?

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

Doing my first push to the master branch, I can't see where to link the push to a work item in Dev Azure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the commit message textbox using a specific syntax `#1589` (where 1589 is the id of the work item)

Comment: Thanks @Philippe. Found it :)